# creating filename by date Laravel

Tags: laravel

The problem is its not saving filename by date . I check by  `dd($date);` it was correct. but when i store by date to filename. its not working as well.

**MaterialsController@store**

```
  $date = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
  $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$date.'/';
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath.$fileName.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(),file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
}
if($uploaded){
   $date = now()->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s');
   Material::create(['description' => $request->input('description'),
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'filename' => $date]);
}
```

**MaterialsController@show**

```
public function show(Material $material)
 {
    $material = Material::find($material->id);
    $directory = config('app.filesDestinationPath').'/'.$material->filename.'/';
    $files = Storage::files($directory);
    return view('materials.show', ['material'=>$material])->with(array('files' => $files));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use Storage::makeDirectory(), so your code gonna be like this(btw, i suggest Y-m-d, so it will not make many folder)

```
$date = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s'); // or date('Y-m-d')
Storage::makeDirectory($date);
```

Comment: Sir is this any way to use `'filename' => $date` this? Cause its the requirement by create folder name like `Y-m-d-H-i-s`

Comment: maybe,i use it for creating new folder by date

Comment: Oh sorry sir. I think i didn't explain as good. My this line is  not working `'filename' => $date` i don't know why. And i was like is there any way to get `date` to `filename` .

Comment: try use date() to get current date , its basic php. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php , read the example #4.

Comment: Believe or not. i just forget to add `filename` to Model. My bad 100%. Thanks for your comment